Why does SELECT DISTINCT col in Snowflake returns a different number of rows than COUNT(DISTINCT col)?
Query 1:
SELECT 
    DISTINCT COL
  FROM 
    TABLE
  WHERE 
    MONTH = '2024-09-01'

Query 2:
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT COL)
  FROM 
    TABLE
  WHERE 
    MONTH = '2024-09-01'

Query 1 returns 27M rows. Query 2 returns a number equal to 40M. I'm using Snowflake database. I have already searched the Internet and have no idea why this is happening.
Update:

COL represents a single column.
COL is of type VARCHAR(256).


What is the result of  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT      DISTINCT COL   FROM      TABLE   WHERE      MONTH = '2024-09-01' ); and second is the distinct query using more than a single column?

Can you please check how many Null values have for the column, that could be the reason for the differacne.

@LukaszSzozda The result of this query is equal to the result of Query 1, which is 27M. COL in DISTINCT COL represents a single column.

@HimanshuKandpal I checked that this column contains about 94k nulls.

@Furia824 - What's the data type for the column? Could be due to differences in collation or how data is cast. Try SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(TRIM(COL)) vs. SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UPPER(TRIM(COL))).

@keithwalsh Sorry, I forgot to mention, this column is of type VARCHAR(256). SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(TRIM(COL)) gives me 27M and SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UPPER(TRIM(COL))) gives 40M.

Hi can you try both the queries with putting NVL and see what i the count that you are getting.

@Furia824 - Try SELECT DISTINCT TO_BINARY(UPPER(TRIM(COL))) vs. COUNT(DISTINCT TO_BINARY(UPPER(TRIM(COL)))) for exact byte-level comparison.

@HimanshuKandpal, a huge number of null values would only give the difference 1 anyway when DISTINCT is used.

@HimanshuKandpal Query 1 returns 27M. Unfortunately, I was not able to check query 2 because I was getting such an error: ”Aggregation policy violation, please contact the policy admin for details."

@keithwalsh Same story as with NVL. Query 1 returns 27M. With Query 2 I get an error: ”Aggregation policy violation, please contact the policy admin for details."

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COL), DP_INTERVAL_LOW(COL), DP_INTERVAL_HIGH(COL)   FROM TABLE WHERE MONTH = '2024-09-01'

You can check if any policy is applied on the table: SELECT * FROM TABLE(information_schema.policy_references(ref_entity_name => 'my_db.my_schema.my_table', ref_entity_domain => 'table'));

Maybe SELECT COL, COUNT(COL) FROM TABLE WHERE MONTH = '2024-09-01' GROUP BY COL would provide some further insight.
